# Git: automatic fetching from remote repositories?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-status

One irritating thing I find about using command line Git is having to manually sync my repository with remote repositories. I constantly get tripped up by commands like "git status" that I (mistakenly) expect to report the difference between my working directory and a repository on GitHub. (Of course it reports the difference between my working directory and my local repository...)

Is there any way to get automatic/implicit fetching, so that remotes are always up to date? I would happily pay a penalty of a few seconds for commands like git status, git merge etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of those commands is already built in.

```
git pull
```

does a fetch and a merge.

For the other one, well....define your own command, such as

```
alias gitfu='git fetch; git status'
```

The shell is yours to command.

Depending on your configuration you may be asked for pass phrase or credentials for each of these.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that actually works ok. Using alias in ~/.gitconfig 'stat = "!git fetch && git status"'. I guess I repeat that for other likely commands.

Comment: but if you have a password on the repo then?

Comment: Then you have to supply that password. If you use an ssh key instead then no need to repeatedly supply a password for this and other Git commands.

Answer (score 10):

In `zsh`, there is [the `git-auto-fetch` plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/git-auto-fetch) which

> Automatically fetches all changes from all remotes while you are working in git-initialized directory.

Just add to your `plugins` in `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 6):

If you would prefer to use a GUI like [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), there's a preference option that checks default remotes every X minutes.

You could also set global alias in the global .gitconfig file under [alias]. Such as `git fetch --all && git status` (add `-s` for short status). Or possibly `git stash && git pull && git stash apply && git status` et al, if you currently have changes. But watch out for merge conflicts.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually not looking for a GUI solution. But I sure would like to streamline the Git cmd-line experience.

Comment: I thought [this Peepcode video about Advanced Git](https://peepcode.com/products/advanced-git) was pretty good. [This dotfiles guide](http://dotfiles.github.com/) although not just git commands may stir some ideas as well.