# Automatically fetching files in git?

Tags: git

I have a question about `git fetch`.
Actually, I know how it works.

But I guess without that command, I can see the changes from `origin/<branch>`.
Lets say in GitHub repo, some files get changed and I can simply see them on my machine by doing `git checkout origin/<branch>` without `git fetch origin/<branch>` command.

Is it a new feature by git?
Automatically fetching remote repo?

Comment: Git itself does not do this. You may have something else configured to run `git fetch` automatically at regular intervals, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: automatic fetching from remote repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464039/git-automatic-fetching-from-remote-repositories)

Comment: @chepner how can I check whether it is configured to run automatically?

Comment: It's not something Git itself knows about. Maybe there's a cron job; maybe it's your IDE. There's no one place you can go to check.

Comment: There *is* a project to add background fetching (via `git maintenance`) to Git, but it's not something that most people should be using yet and it's not enabled by default. I used to run some systems with mirrors that would auto-fetch regularly (5 and 15 minutes intervals, and 1 hour intervals) for internal corporate repositories, but that's rather different usage. We wrote all our own scripts to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally due to an IDE like VSCode, which will fetch on a regular basis.

Check the [`git.autofetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46710423/6309) setting.

But as commented, outside of a third-party tool doing the fetching, `git` alone would not.