# Visual Studio Code Git Auto Sync

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there a way I can configure VS Code to automatically sync changes (maybe at a periodic interval), without me having to click this button?

[image]

Comment: when you are working on a branch why do you need to get every commit pushed by your team members the moment they get committed

Comment: for fetch, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68959453/11107541. for push, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34719129/11107541.